# Java equivalent to string.format() in python

Tags: java

I want to print something like a chart with minimum space in each block and a certain alignment to the space it takes up.
Let's say I had a chart in python like:

```
Format = """  X  |  Y  |  Z  
{:^5}|{:>5}|{:>5}"""
print(Format.format(4, 64, 23))
```

How would I do this in java. Everything I've tried doesn't include minimum white space or alignment.

```
System.out.println("  X  |  Y  |  Z  ");
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0}|{1}|{2}", 4, 64, 23));
```

Comment: You mean like [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) **or** use `System.out.printf` (which can use the same `String, Object...`) to output it directly, like

```
System.out.printf("%-5s %5s %5s%n", "X", "Y", "Z");
System.out.printf("%-5d % 5d % 5d%n", 4, 64, 23);
```

and I get

```
X         Y     Z
4        64    23
```